# VB.net and running an external .exe program in both Administrator mode and compatibility mode (windows xp sp2)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, compatibility, compatibility-mode

Hey all i am trying to find some code that would allow me to run a program with administrator rights and also windows xp sp2 compatibility mode. But i have not yet found any code to do that using VB.net

Any help/links would be great! Thanks!

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have to pass command line params, you can create a shortcut to the exe, and set it to compatibility mode and admin there. Then just ShellExecute the shortcut.